# How to create a whatsapp like recording button with slide to cancel

Tags: android, whatsapp

As in whatsapp I need a recoding button and a slide to cancel and fade animation , I have searched for similar code but didn't got one.
I am new to android programming any help or link could be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have created a github project.You can take a look at it https://github.com/sarathnk/Audio

```
audioSendButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slideText
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    params.leftMargin = dp(30);
                    slideText.setLayoutParams(params);
                    ViewProxy.setAlpha(slideText, 1);
                    startedDraggingX = -1;
                    // startRecording();
                    startrecord();
                    audioSendButton.getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    recordPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    startedDraggingX = -1;
                    stoprecord();
                    // stopRecording(true);
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    float x = motionEvent.getX();
                    if (x < -distCanMove) {
                        stoprecord();
                        // stopRecording(false);
                    }
                    x = x + ViewProxy.getX(audioSendButton);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slideText
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    if (startedDraggingX != -1) {
                        float dist = (x - startedDraggingX);
                        params.leftMargin = dp(30) + (int) dist;
                        slideText.setLayoutParams(params);
                        float alpha = 1.0f + dist / distCanMove;
                        if (alpha > 1) {
                            alpha = 1;
                        } else if (alpha < 0) {
                            alpha = 0;
                        }
                        ViewProxy.setAlpha(slideText, alpha);
                    }
                    if (x <= ViewProxy.getX(slideText) + slideText.getWidth()
                            + dp(30)) {
                        if (startedDraggingX == -1) {
                            startedDraggingX = x;
                            distCanMove = (recordPanel.getMeasuredWidth()
                                    - slideText.getMeasuredWidth() - dp(48)) / 2.0f;
                            if (distCanMove <= 0) {
                                distCanMove = dp(80);
                            } else if (distCanMove > dp(80)) {
                                distCanMove = dp(80);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (params.leftMargin > dp(30)) {
                        params.leftMargin = dp(30);
                        slideText.setLayoutParams(params);
                        ViewProxy.setAlpha(slideText, 1);
                        startedDraggingX = -1;
                    }
                }
                view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great Work here i want to store the recorded audio

Answer (score 8):

you can use the library that i have  made [RecordView](https://github.com/3llomi/RecordView)

it's easy to setup and it's simulates the same behavior like WhatsApp.

Simply add the Views `RecordView` and `RecordButton`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.devlomi.recordview.MainActivity">

<com.devlomi.record_view.RecordView
    android:id="@+id/record_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/record_button"
    app:slide_to_cancel_arrow="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left"
    app:slide_to_cancel_text="Slide To Cancel"
    app:slide_to_cancel_margin_right="10dp"/>

<com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton
    android:id="@+id/record_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mic"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white"
    />
```

then in your Activity

```
    RecordView recordView = (RecordView) findViewById(R.id.record_view);
    RecordButton recordButton = (RecordButton) 
     findViewById(R.id.record_button);

    //IMPORTANT
    recordButton.setRecordView(recordView);
```

lastly you can handle the Record States

- **onStart** when start Recording
- **onCancel** when swiping to cancel
- **onFinish** when finishes record and it returns the recorded time in millis
- **onLessThanSecond** when the record time <= 1Second

  ```
  recordView.setOnRecordListener(this);


      @Override
      public void onStart() {
          //Start Recording..
          Log.d("RecordView", "onStart");
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancel() {
          //On Swipe To Cancel
          Log.d("RecordView", "onCancel");

      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish(long recordTime) {
          //Stop Recording..
          String time = getHumanTimeText(recordTime);
          Log.d("RecordView", "onFinish");

          Log.d("RecordTime", time);
      }

      @Override
      public void onLessThanSecond() {
          //When the record time is less than One Second
          Log.d("RecordView", "onLessThanSecond");
      }
  ```

Comment: How do I get the recorded file path?

Comment: it's not implemented in the library, you can use `MediaRecorder` for example to record voice and save it to the device.

Comment: This is the best one so far

Answer (score 7):

You can put a scale animation on the button and touch gestures to detect the user's movements..

Checkout the sample here..
https://github.com/varunjohn/Audio-Recording-Animation

This sample also has delete animation and lock feature similar to whatsapp..

[image]

**Check Sample code here**

```
imageViewAudio.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (isDeleting) {
                return true;
            }

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                cancelOffset = (float) (imageViewAudio.getX() / 2.8);
                lockOffset = (float) (imageViewAudio.getX() / 2.5);

                if (firstX == 0) {
                    firstX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                }

                if (firstY == 0) {
                    firstY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                }

                startRecord();

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    stopRecording(RecordingBehaviour.RELEASED);
                }

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                if (stopTrackingAction) {
                    return true;
                }

                UserBehaviour direction = UserBehaviour.NONE;

                float motionX = Math.abs(firstX - motionEvent.getRawX());
                float motionY = Math.abs(firstY - motionEvent.getRawY());

                if (motionX > directionOffset &&
                        motionX > directionOffset &&
                        lastX < firstX && lastY < firstY) {

                    if (motionX > motionY && lastX < firstX) {
                        direction = UserBehaviour.CANCELING;

                    } else if (motionY > motionX && lastY < firstY) {
                        direction = UserBehaviour.LOCKING;
                    }

                } else if (motionX > motionY && motionX > directionOffset && lastX < firstX) {
                    direction = UserBehaviour.CANCELING;
                } else if (motionY > motionX && motionY > directionOffset && lastY < firstY) {
                    direction = UserBehaviour.LOCKING;
                }

                if (direction == UserBehaviour.CANCELING) {
                    if (userBehaviour == UserBehaviour.NONE || motionEvent.getRawY() + imageViewAudio.getWidth() / 2 > firstY) {
                        userBehaviour = UserBehaviour.CANCELING;
                    }

                    if (userBehaviour == UserBehaviour.CANCELING) {
                        translateX(-(firstX - motionEvent.getRawX()));
                    }
                } else if (direction == UserBehaviour.LOCKING) {
                    if (userBehaviour == UserBehaviour.NONE || motionEvent.getRawX() + imageViewAudio.getWidth() / 2 > firstX) {
                        userBehaviour = UserBehaviour.LOCKING;
                    }

                    if (userBehaviour == UserBehaviour.LOCKING) {
                        translateY(-(firstY - motionEvent.getRawY()));
                    }
                }

                lastX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                lastY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            }
            view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Source is free?

Comment: @AdolfoJulcamoro sure go on use it, its my library..

Comment: @varunjohn1990 is it available in iOS too?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the send button as in whatsapp application which can be either in send state or record state. You can take a look at it here on my [blog post](http://gunhansancar.com/anim-button-inspired-by-whatsapp/).

The usage is very simple.

```
<com.gunhansancar.android.animbutton.AnimButton
        android:id="@+id/animButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:first="@drawable/ic_mic"
        app:second="@drawable/ic_send" />
```

You just have to set first and second drawable. And also you have to set the state by calling goToState() method.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code provided by @3llomi to create a class that only produces the expanding button without the cancel on slide animation. As I wanted to place my buttons inside a recyclerview the cancel animation would just have overcrowded things. My code comes with a callback that delivers an audiofile stored in cache when recording is completed
these are the necessary clases and xmls:

```java
public class RecordButton extends AppCompatImageView implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private ScaleAnim scaleAnim;
    private boolean listenForRecord = true;
    private int commId;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    private boolean isRecording;

    private static SoundPool soundPool = null;
    private static int soundStart,soundEnd;


    public RecordButton(Context context, int id) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
        commId=id;
    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public RecordButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }


    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RecordButton);

            int imageResource = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.RecordButton_mic_icon, -1);

            if (imageResource != -1) {
                setTheImageResource(imageResource);
            }

            typedArray.recycle();
        }

        if (soundPool==null){
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(5)
                    .build();
            //these are just two wav files with short intro and exit sounds
            soundStart=soundPool.load(getContext(),R.raw.start_recording_sound,0);
            soundEnd=soundPool.load(getContext(),R.raw.end_recording_sound,0);
        }

        scaleAnim = new ScaleAnim(this);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private void setTheImageResource(int imageResource) {
        Drawable image = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), imageResource);
        setImageDrawable(image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setClip(this);
    }

    public void setClip(View v) {
        if (v.getParent() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup) v).setClipChildren(false);
            ((ViewGroup) v).setClipToPadding(false);
        }

        if (v.getParent() instanceof View) {
            setClip((View) v.getParent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (isListenForRecord()) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ((RecordButton) v).startScale();
                    soundPool.play(soundStart,1,1,0,0,1);
                    startRecording();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopRecording();
                    soundPool.play(soundEnd,1,1,0,0,1);
                    ((RecordButton) v).stopScale();
                    break;
            }

        }
        return isListenForRecord();
    }

    File file;
    //audio recording tools
    private void startRecording() {
        if (isRecording){
            stopRecording();
        }
        String fileName=getContext().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+commId+"_"+new Date().getTime()+".amr";
        file=new File(fileName);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
        recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12000);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),fileName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        recorder.start();

        setIsRecording(true);
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (isRecording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            setIsRecording(false);
            recordingFinishedListener.onRecordingFinished(file);
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    private void setIsRecording(boolean isRecording){
        this.isRecording=isRecording;
    }


    protected void startScale() {
        scaleAnim.start();
    }

    protected void stopScale() {
        scaleAnim.stop();
    }

    public void setListenForRecord(boolean listenForRecord) {
        this.listenForRecord = listenForRecord;
    }

    public boolean isListenForRecord() {
        return listenForRecord;
    }

    //callback for when a recording has been made
    public interface RecordingFinishedListener{
        void onRecordingFinished(File file);
    }

    RecordingFinishedListener recordingFinishedListener;

    public void setRecordingFinishedListener(RecordingFinishedListener recordingFinishedListener) {
        this.recordingFinishedListener = recordingFinishedListener;
    }
}
```

then the class responsible for animations which allows you to define the degree of the expansion

```java
public class ScaleAnim {
    private View view;
    public ScaleAnim(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    void start() {
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.3f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1.3f);
        set.setDuration(150);
        set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        set.playTogether(scaleY, scaleX);
        set.start();
    }

    void stop() {
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.0f);
        //        scaleY.setDuration(250);
        //        scaleY.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1.0f);
        //        scaleX.setDuration(250);
        //        scaleX.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        set.setDuration(150);
        set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        set.playTogether(scaleY, scaleX);
        set.start();
    }
}
```

and the attrs.xml file. The rest are just a mic icon and some some sounds that you can find by yourself

```xml
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RecordButton">
        <attr name="mic_icon" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

by setting the RecordingFinishedListener on the recordbutton you can go on to process the recorded sound.