# How to make recording button like WhatsApp?

Tags: android, animation, button, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a button such as Whatsapp (for Android) to record audio, and with the same animation. But how should I do? With Floating Action Button of material design i can't.

Comment: You should show what you've already tried. Users are more likely to help you fix your code, than write it completely for you.

Answer (score 2):

did you saw the telegram code ? maybe you can find some "lights" https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Answer (score 2):

Check this link. 
https://github.com/sarathnk/Audio

As suggested here: 
[How to create a whatsapp like recording button with slide to cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711549/how-to-create-a-whatsapp-like-recording-button-with-slide-to-cancel)